# How do you know which trigger caused an update which caused another trigger to run?

Tags: trigger

I have an custom object called Address which looks up to Account. Whenever an Account is updated, I want to update a field on any child Address records, in a trigger. I also have a trigger on the Address object, which will be fired when the Address is updated.

In the Address trigger, how can I tell the difference between an Address being updated directly and an Account being updated, causing an update on the Address?

Comment: By definition you know this - the top-level invocation (trigger on Account vs trigger on Address) contains this information. You can pass it down to e.g. your handler. Good read: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71400/controlling-trigger-execution/71403#71403

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be reportable, you could add 2 checkboxes to the object being updated and title them something like 'Address updated directly' 'Address updated through Acct'. Then, in each flow, just add another update field to change the related checkbox to 'true'.  This will give you reportable fields to view en-masse what was updated directly and what was done through the Account being updated.

For a non-reportable option that is visible at the record-level, you could make sure the chatter field is enabled and visible.  Then, as part of each flow, add an Action for 'Post to Chatter' and customize a message stating whether or not the address was updated directly or through the Account being updated.